# Adding include directories to CMake when calling it from the command line

Tags: c++, cmake

I'm in a situation where I should not disturb the existing CMakeLists.txt files, but I still should add some g++ system include directory to my build.

In other words, I need `-isystem /path/to/my/include` added to my compiler flags, but when calling something like `cmake ..`.

Maybe something like `cmake .. -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS="$CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS -isystem /path/to/my/include"`? Is there a way to do this?

Comment: so you want to add compilation flags and then remove them? Or do you just want to add them?

Comment: I just want to add them without touching CMakeLists.

Comment: Note that the variable reference, `$CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS`, would reference a shell variable. Probably not what you would want. Actually, it should be useless on the command line.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I have the same problem. I found two solutions:

1. The [one proposed by sakra in a previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25849571/adding-include-directories-to-cmake-when-calling-it-from-the-command-line/25851074#25851074), i.e. setting an environment variable with C++ flags:

   ```
   export CXXFLAGS=-isystem\ /path/to/my/include
   cmake <path to my sources>
   ```

   **OR** the same thing, but environment variable are set only for this **CMake** call:

   ```
   CXXFLAGS=-isystem\ /path/to/my/include cmake <path to my sources>
   ```

   **IMPORTANT**: you *must* clean your build directory (i.e. clean the CMake cache) before launching any of this form. Without cleaning the cache, CMake will continue using your cached `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` from the previous run.
2. Directly setting `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` in cmake string:

   ```
   cmake -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS=-isystem\ /path/to/my/include <path to my sources>
   ```

I believe that it can be done by a more 'native' way, but I didn't find a variable responsible for paths to headers in CMake.

Comment: That IMPORTANT tip saved my sanity!

Comment: what if i need multiple directories added to include path from command line?

Comment: You can pass more than one -isystem parameter (like using a usual `-I` way, i. e. `-isystem path0 -isystem path1`)

Comment: Nothing works from this

Answer (score 17):

You can set the environment variable `CXXFLAGS` before invoking CMake.

```
$ export CXXFLAGS=-isystem\ /path/to/my/include
$ cmake ..
```

CMake will the initialize the cache variable `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` with the flags from the environment variable. The variable affects all build types.

Comment: or without `export` form: `CXXFLAGS=-isystem\ /path/to/my/include cmake ..`

Answer (score 13):

Using `-DCMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES=<something>` worked for me even without toolchain file. This avoids cluttering compiler flags.

Comment: I don't think you should override this. It is meant to be set by toolchain files. If you override it you might end up not being able to find standard C++ headers.

Comment: This still can be used as a workaround for loading Cmake-based projects into IDEs. Also when LLVM toolchain is used, this option helps force Cmake to see standard headers from LLVM rather than those installed in the system (typically from GNU toolchain of a different version).

Answer (score 5):

Just an additional note to the other answers: with CMake **3.15.3** on **macOS 10.14.5**, only the solution using the CMake flag seems to work properly.

So, in my case, only this solution worked fine:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS=-I\ /path/to/include <path/to/source>
```

or

```
cmake -DCMAKE_C_FLAGS=-I\ /path/to/include <path/to/source>
```