# How to compile LLVM against a custom glibc?

Tags: vim, cmake, clang, llvm, glibc

I'm using [YouCompleteMe](http://valloric.github.io/YouCompleteMe/) Vim plugin for text completion (installed through [Vundle](https://github.com/gmarik/Vundle.vim)). YouCompleteMe uses Clang for text completion for C-family languages (C, C++, Objective-C, Objective-C++). However, after YouCompleteMe update (via `:VundleUpdate` in Vim) YouCompleteMe ceased to work.

In short, the question is: **How can I compile Clang against a custom glibc version?** Debian Wheezy ships with glibc 2.13, and it seems that newest Clang version requires at least glibc 2.15 (explanation in more detail below). Just in case, I'm using Debian Wheezy, x86-64 and a custom Linux kernel version 4.0.0-rc6.

So I downloaded LLVM from the git mirror according to the instructions on [LLVM website](http://llvm.org/docs/GettingStarted.html#git-mirror):

```
$ mkdir ~/code
$ cd ~/code/llvm_source_tree
$ git clone http://llvm.org/git/llvm.git
$ cd ~/code/llvm_source_tree/llvm/tools
$ git clone http://llvm.org/git/clang.git
$ cd ~/code/llvm_source_tree/llvm/projects
$ git clone http://llvm.org/git/compiler-rt.git
$ git clone http://llvm.org/git/test-suite.git
$ cd ~/code/llvm_source_tree/llvm
$ git config branch.master.rebase true
```

Then, I compiled LLVM following the instructions on [LLVM website](http://llvm.org/docs/GettingStarted.html#compiling-the-llvm-suite-source-code):

```
$ cmake -G 'Unix Makefiles' -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE='Release' ~/code/llvm_source_tree/llvm/
$ make -j 5
$ su
# make install
```

Everything fine so far, so I continued with YouCompleteMe installation by compiling the YouCompleteMe support libraries following [YouCompleteMe install instructions](http://valloric.github.io/YouCompleteMe/#full-installation-guide):

```
$ mkdir ~/ycm_build
$ cd ~/ycm_build
$ cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" -DEXTERNAL_LIBCLANG_PATH=/usr/local/lib/libclang.so . ~/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/third_party/ycmd/cpp
$ make ycm_support_libs
```

Then I ran Vim and I noticed that YouCompleteMe still does not seem to work. When I enter edit mode in Vim in some C++ file (for example), YouCompleteMe prints error: `The ycmd server SHUT DOWN (restart with :YcmRestartServer). Stderr (last 30 lines):`, and after that `:YcmRestartServer` prints `Restarting ycmd server...`, then `('Connection aborted.', error(111, 'Connection refused'))`).

`:YcmDebugInfo` prints the following:

```
Printing YouCompleteMe debug information...
-- Server crashed, no debug info from server
-- Server running at: http://127.0.0.1:37730
-- Server process ID: 22358
-- Server logfiles:
--   /tmp/ycm_temp/server_37730_stdout.log
--   /tmp/ycm_temp/server_37730_stderr.log
```

`/tmp/ycm_temp/server_37730_stdout.log` is empty, but `/tmp/ycm_temp/server_37730_stderr.log` contains the following lines:

```
2015-05-20 17:06:46,126 - DEBUG - No global extra conf, not calling method YcmCorePreload
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 162, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "/home/user/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/third_party/ycmd/ycmd/__main__.py", line 164, in 
    Main()
  File "/home/user/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/third_party/ycmd/ycmd/__main__.py", line 150, in Main
    from ycmd import handlers
  File "/home/user/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/third_party/ycmd/ycmd/../ycmd/handlers.py", line 30, in 
    str( e ) ) )
RuntimeError: Error importing ycm_core. Are you sure you have placed a version 3.2+ libclang.[so|dll|dylib] in folder "/home/user/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/third_party/ycmd"? See the Installation Guide in the docs. Full error: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by /home/user/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/third_party/ycmd/ycmd/../libclang.so)
```

So I ran the tests of YouCompleteMe and got this error when running `./vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/third_party/ycmd/run_tests.sh`:

```
[ 98%] Building CXX object ycm/tests/CMakeFiles/ycm_core_tests.dir/main.cpp.o
[100%] Building CXX object ycm/tests/CMakeFiles/ycm_core_tests.dir/TestUtils.cpp.o
Linking CXX executable ycm_core_tests
../../clang+llvm-3.6.0-x86_64-linux-gnu/lib/libclang.so: undefined reference to `posix_spawn@GLIBC_2.15'
../../clang+llvm-3.6.0-x86_64-linux-gnu/lib/libclang.so: undefined reference to `memcpy@GLIBC_2.14'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[3]: *** [ycm/tests/ycm_core_tests] Error 1
make[2]: *** [ycm/tests/CMakeFiles/ycm_core_tests.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [ycm/tests/CMakeFiles/ycm_core_tests.dir/rule] Error 2
make: *** [ycm_core_tests] Error 2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/third_party/ycmd/build.py", line 196, in 
    Main()
  File "/home/user/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/third_party/ycmd/build.py", line 189, in Main
    BuildYcmdLibs( GetCmakeArgs( args ) )
  File "/home/user/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/third_party/ycmd/build.py", line 152, in BuildYcmdLibs
    _err = sys.stderr )
  File "/home/user/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/third_party/ycmd/third_party/sh/sh.py", line 1021, in __call__
    return RunningCommand(cmd, call_args, stdin, stdout, stderr)
  File "/home/user/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/third_party/ycmd/third_party/sh/sh.py", line 486, in __init__
    self.wait()
  File "/home/user/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/third_party/ycmd/third_party/sh/sh.py", line 500, in wait
    self.handle_command_exit_code(exit_code)
  File "/home/user/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/third_party/ycmd/third_party/sh/sh.py", line 516, in handle_command_exit_code
    raise exc(self.ran, self.process.stdout, self.process.stderr)
sh.ErrorReturnCode_2: 

  RAN: '/usr/bin/make -j 8 ycm_core_tests'

  STDOUT:


  STDERR:
```

So it seems that Clang 3.6.0 may require glibc 2.15 or newer. Debian Wheezy ships with glibc 2.13. So decided to install the latest stable version of glibc (currently 2.21). I had already earlier compiled binutils and installed it to `/usr/local/bin/`, so I didn't need to do that now.

So I downloaded http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/glibc/glibc-2.21.tar.bz2 and then unpacked it and compiled the source and installed it:

```
$ cd ~/code
$ mkdir ~/code/glibc
$ cd ~/code/glibc
$ mv -iv ~/downloads/glibc-2.21.tar.bz2 .
$ tar xjvf glibc-2.21.tar.bz2
$ cd glibc-2.21
$ mkdir build
$ cd build
$ ../configure --with-binutils=/usr/local/bin --prefix=/usr/local/glibc/glibc-2.21
$ make -j 5
$ su
# make install
```

Then I recompiled LLVM. I passed in `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` environment variable the g++ linker flags to `cmake` following Employed Russian's answer to SO question [Multiple glibc libraries on a single host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/847179/multiple-glibc-libraries-on-a-single-host/851229#851229):

```
$ export CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS='-Wl,--rpath=/usr/local/glibc/glibc-2.21 -Wl,--dynamic-linker=/usr/local/glibc/glibc-2.21/ld-linux.so.2'
$ cmake -G 'Unix Makefiles' -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE='Release' ~/code/llvm_source_tree/llvm/
$ make -j 5
```

And then I recompiled the YouCompleteMe support libs, again passing g++ linker flags to `cmake` in `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS`:

```
$ export CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS='-Wl,--rpath=/usr/local/glibc/glibc-2.21 -Wl,--dynamic-linker=/usr/local/glibc/glibc-2.21/ld-linux.so.2'
$ cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" -DEXTERNAL_LIBCLANG_PATH=/usr/local/lib/libclang.so . ~/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/third_party/ycmd/cpp
```

But the problem with YouCompleteMe persists and tests still fail in the same way. Maybe `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` is not a sufficient way to pass g++ linker flags to `cmake`? I also tried using `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` when compiling LLVM against glibc 2.21:

```
$ cd ~/code/llvm_source_tree
$ mkdir build2
$ cd build2
$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/local/glibc/glibc-2.21/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"
$ cmake -G 'Unix Makefiles' -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE='Release' ~/code/llvm_source_tree/llvm/
```

And got this error:

```
cmake: error while loading shared libraries: __vdso_time: invalid mode for dlopen(): Invalid argument
```

Then I also tried `LD_PRELOAD`:

```
$ export LD_PRELOAD='/usr/local/glibc/glibc-2.21/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 /usr/local/glibc/glibc-2.21/lib/libc.so.6'
$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/local/glibc/glibc-2.21/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"
$ cmake -G 'Unix Makefiles' -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE='Release' ~/code/llvm_source_tree/llvm/
```

And got these errors:

```
-- The C compiler identification is unknown
-- The CXX compiler identification is unknown
Inconsistency detected by ld.so: dl-minimal.c: 136: realloc: Assertion `ptr == alloc_last_block' failed!
```

Then I also tried adding `/usr/local/glibc/glibc-2.21/lib/ld-2.21.so` to `export LD_PRELOAD`, but it didn't change the error message in any way.

I'm quite sure that Clang does not require glibc 2.15 (exact) even if the other missing symbol (`posix_spawn@GLIBC_2.15`) is originally from glibc 2.15, as glibc according to its documentation attempts to maintain backward compatibility and anyway the other missing symbol (`memcpy@GLIBC_2.14`) is from glibc 2.14. So I didn't try this all with glibc 2.15. But now I'm out of ideas and any advice would be appreciated.

### Edit 1

I followed [Employed Russian's answer (below)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30352255/how-to-compile-llvm-against-a-custom-glibc/30361522#30361522), but my problem did not change in any way. So I concluded that `export CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` is not the right way to pass g++ linker flags to `cmake`. `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` is the name of an variable **internal** to `cmake`, but `cmake` does not care at all about an **environment** variable with the same name (`CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS`). `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` can be defined directly in `CMakeLists.txt`, but in [LLVM compiling instructions](http://llvm.org/docs/GettingStarted.html#compiling-the-llvm-suite-source-code) no master `CMakeLists.txt` is used and I don't want to recreate LLVM compiling script from scratch if there's some more practical option. But there are still 3 other options available which I could find:

1. `cmake` initializes `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` from an environment variable named `CXXFLAGS`. See sakra's answer to SO question [Adding include directories to cmake when calling it from command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25849571/adding-include-directories-to-cmake-when-calling-it-from-command-line/25851074#25851074).

```
$ export CXXFLAGS='-Wl,--rpath=/usr/local/glibc/glibc-2.21 -Wl,--dynamic-linker=/usr/local/glibc/glibc-2.21/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2'
$ cmake -G 'Unix Makefiles' -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE='Release' ~/code/llvm_source_tree/llvm/
$ make
```

2. `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` can also be initialized from the command line using `-DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS`:

```
$ cmake -G 'Unix Makefiles' -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE='Release' -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS='-Wl,--rpath=/usr/local/glibc/glibc-2.21 -Wl,--dynamic-linker=/usr/local/glibc/glibc-2.21/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2' ~/code/llvm_source_tree/llvm/
$ make
```

3. `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` can also be initialized from the command line using `-DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS:STRING` (see [Building mpllibs](https://abel.web.elte.hu/mpllibs/build.html)):

```
$ cmake -G 'Unix Makefiles' -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE='Release' -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS:STRING='-Wl,--rpath=/usr/local/glibc/glibc-2.21 -Wl,--dynamic-linker=/usr/local/glibc/glibc-2.21/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2' ~/code/llvm_source_tree/llvm/
$ make
```

All of these 3 options produces the exactly same result: compiling LLVM ends with the same error that is related to targets `llvm-tblgen` and `intrinsics_gen` (the only differences between the 3 `Makefile`'s produced above by `cmake` commands are in directory names, caused by the fact that each build was done in different directory). It seems that the target `llvm-tblgen` gets compiled and linked appropriately, but after that the target `llvm-tblgen` seems to be a dependency of the target `intrinsics_gen`, and somehow `llvm-tblgen` cannot be found. These are the last lines of the output of `make` (these are identical for each of the 3 builds above):

```
Linking CXX executable ../../bin/llvm-tblgen
[  4%] Built target llvm-tblgen
Scanning dependencies of target intrinsics_gen
[  4%] Building Intrinsics.gen...
/bin/sh: 1: ../../../bin/llvm-tblgen: not found
make[2]: *** [include/llvm/IR/Intrinsics.gen.tmp] Error 127
make[1]: *** [include/llvm/IR/CMakeFiles/intrinsics_gen.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I wonder if this if this is a bug in LLVM or is setting `cmake` variable `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` the way I did (in the 3 builds above) sufficient or is this caused by something else. Any ideas how to continue would be greatly appreciated.

### Edit 2

As suggested by Employed Russian in his comment ([below his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30352255/how-to-compile-llvm-against-a-custom-glibc/30361522#30361522)):

```
$ export CXXFLAGS='-Wl,--rpath=/usr/local/glibc/glibc-2.21 -Wl,--dynamic-linker=/usr/local/glibc/glibc-2.21/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2'
$ cmake -G 'Unix Makefiles' -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE='Release' ~/code/llvm_source_tree/llvm/
$ make
```

This also caused a compiling error related to targets `llvm-tblgen` and `intrinsics_gen`, but the error was different compared to the prior error. These are the last lines of `make` output:

```
Linking CXX executable ../../bin/llvm-tblgen
[  4%] Built target llvm-tblgen
Scanning dependencies of target intrinsics_gen
[  4%] Building Intrinsics.gen...
../../../bin/llvm-tblgen: error while loading shared libraries: libtinfo.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
make[2]: *** [include/llvm/IR/Intrinsics.gen.tmp] Error 127
make[1]: *** [include/llvm/IR/CMakeFiles/intrinsics_gen.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

So it seems that `llvm-tblgen` is now found, but there's an error loading shared library `libtinfo.so.5`. So I changed `--rpath=/usr/local/glibc/glibc-2.21` to `--rpath=/usr/local/glibc/glibc-2.21/lib` and tried again:

```
$ export CXXFLAGS='-Wl,--rpath=/usr/local/glibc/glibc-2.21/lib -Wl,--dynamic-linker=/usr/local/glibc/glibc-2.21/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2'
$ cmake -G 'Unix Makefiles' -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE='Release' ~/code/llvm_source_tree/llvm/
$ make
```

However, this change of `--rpath` did not change the error message produced by `make` at all. I wonder where this shared library `libtinfo.so.5` should be located.

Then I encountered [Building the Clang + LLVM compilers website](http://ftp.math.utah.edu/pub/llvm/) and tried adding `-std=c++11` to `CXXFLAGS`:

```
$ export CXXFLAGS='-std=c++11 -Wl,--rpath=/usr/local/glibc/glibc-2.21 -Wl,--dynamic-linker=/usr/local/glibc/glibc-2.21/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2'
$ cmake -G 'Unix Makefiles' -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE='Release' ~/code/llvm_source_tree/llvm/
$ make
```

But it didn't help, the error message is identical, that is, shared library `libtinfo.so.5` still cannot be found. Maybe my `g++` version is too old, it's `g++` 4.7.2 that is shipped with Debian Wheezy (`g++ --version` prints `g++ (Debian 4.7.2-5) 4.7.2`). The author of [Building the Clang + LLVM compilers website](http://ftp.math.utah.edu/pub/llvm/) writes that his attempt to build LLVM on Fedora 15 using only `g++` 4.7.1 failed, whereas compiling it with several restarts with different `g++` versions (4.8, 4.8.0, 4.7.1) finally succeeded (described on the website). Any ideas?

### Edit 3

As suggested by Employed Russian, I recompiled glibc 2.21 with `-Wl,--rpath=/usr/local/glibc/glibc-2.21/lib:/lib:/usr/lib:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu`:

```
$ cd ~/code/glibc/glibc-2.21
$ mv -iv build old_build
$ mkdir build
$ cd build
$ export LD_FLAGS='-Wl,--rpath=/usr/local/glibc/glibc-2.21/lib:/lib:/usr/lib:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu'
$ ../configure --with-binutils=/usr/local/bin --prefix=/usr/local/glibc/glibc-2.21
$ make -j 5
```

`make check` produced some errors:

```
Summary of test results:
    112 FAIL
   2073 PASS
    199 XFAIL
      3 XPASS
make[1]: *** [tests] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/user/code/glibc/glibc-2.21'
make: *** [check] Error 2
```

Anyway, I installed the newly compiled glibc 2.21:

```
$ su
# make install
```

`make install` produced this warning:

```
/home/user/code/glibc/glibc-2.21/build/elf/ldconfig: Warning: ignoring configuration file that cannot be opened: /usr/local/glibc/glibc-2.21/etc/ld.so.conf: No such file or directory
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/user/code/glibc/glibc-2.21'
```

Then I recompiled LLVM again with: `-Wl,--rpath=/usr/local/glibc/glibc-2.21/lib:/lib:/usr/lib:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu`:

```
$ export CXXFLAGS='-std=c++11 -Wl,--rpath=/usr/local/glibc/glibc-2.21/lib:/lib:/usr/lib:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -Wl,--dynamic-linker=/usr/local/glibc/glibc-2.21/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2'
$ cmake -G 'Unix Makefiles' -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE='Release' ~/code/llvm_source_tree/llvm/
$ make
```

But `libstdc++.so.6` was missing:

```
Linking CXX executable ../../bin/llvm-tblgen
[  4%] Built target llvm-tblgen
Scanning dependencies of target intrinsics_gen
[  4%] Building Intrinsics.gen...
../../../bin/llvm-tblgen: error while loading shared libraries: libstdc++.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
make[2]: *** [include/llvm/IR/Intrinsics.gen.tmp] Error 127
make[1]: *** [include/llvm/IR/CMakeFiles/intrinsics_gen.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

So I concluded that there must be still some other library directory that is needed for `--rpath`.

```
$ cd /usr
$ sudo find . -name 'libstdc++.so.6'
./lib32/debug/libstdc++.so.6
./lib32/libstdc++.so.6
./lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/debug/libstdc++.so.6
./lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
./lib/git-annex.linux/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
./lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
```

Of these, `./lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6` looks most suitable to me. So I added `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu` to `--rpath`, and recompiled glibc 2.21 once again:

```
$ cd ~/code/glibc/glibc-2.21
$ mv -iv build old_build2
$ mkdir build
$ cd build
$ export LD_FLAGS='-Wl,--rpath=/usr/local/glibc/glibc-2.21/lib:/lib:/usr/lib:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu'
$ ../configure --with-binutils=/usr/local/bin --prefix=/usr/local/glibc/glibc-2.21
$ make -j 5
```

I didn't bother to `make check` this time but rather continued directly with the installation:

```
$ su
# make install
```

And got the same seemingly harmless warning:

```
/home/user/code/glibc/glibc-2.21/build/elf/ldconfig: Warning: ignoring configuration file that cannot be opened: /usr/local/glibc/glibc-2.21/etc/ld.so.conf: No such file or directory
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/user/code/glibc/glibc-2.21'
```

So I added `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu` to `--rpath` for LLVM, and recompiled LLVM:

```
$ export CXXFLAGS='-std=c++11 -Wl,--rpath=/usr/local/glibc/glibc-2.21/lib:/lib:/usr/lib:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -Wl,--dynamic-linker=/usr/local/glibc/glibc-2.21/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2'
$ cmake -G 'Unix Makefiles' -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE='Release' ~/code/llvm_source_tree/llvm/
$ make
```

The build was successful, so I installed LLVM:

```
$ su
# make install
```

Then I recompiled YouCompleteMe support libs with the same `CXXFLAGS` I used for compiling LLVM:

```
$ export CXXFLAGS='-std=c++11 -Wl,--rpath=/usr/local/glibc/glibc-2.21/lib:/lib:/usr/lib:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -Wl,--dynamic-linker=/usr/local/glibc/glibc-2.21/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2'
$ cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" -DEXTERNAL_LIBCLANG_PATH=/usr/local/lib/libclang.so . ~/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/third_party/ycmd/cpp
$ make ycm_support_libs
```

This build was successful, too. Then I reinstalled YouCompleteMe:

```
$ cd
$ .vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/install.sh
```

Completion seems to work. Then I ran the tests of YouCompleteMe:

```
$ .vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/run_tests.sh
```

OK, completion still works.

```
$ .vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/third_party/ycmd/run_tests.sh
```

This caused a problem. It seems that this `.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/third_party/ycmd/run_tests.sh` recompiles support libs - without using my `Makefile` - and therefore breaks the support libs. Solution is **not** to run `.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/third_party/ycmd/run_tests.sh`.

```
[100%] Building CXX object ycm/tests/CMakeFiles/ycm_core_tests.dir/TestUtils.cpp.o
Linking CXX executable ycm_core_tests
../../clang+llvm-3.6.0-x86_64-linux-gnu/lib/libclang.so: undefined reference to `posix_spawn@GLIBC_2.15'
../../clang+llvm-3.6.0-x86_64-linux-gnu/lib/libclang.so: undefined reference to `memcpy@GLIBC_2.14'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[3]: *** [ycm/tests/ycm_core_tests] Error 1
make[2]: *** [ycm/tests/CMakeFiles/ycm_core_tests.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [ycm/tests/CMakeFiles/ycm_core_tests.dir/rule] Error 2
make: *** [ycm_core_tests] Error 2
```

So I recompiled the support libs the same way I recently did and after that and reinstalled YouCompleteMe once more:

```
$ export CXXFLAGS='-std=c++11 -Wl,--rpath=/usr/local/glibc/glibc-2.21/lib:/lib:/usr/lib:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -Wl,--dynamic-linker=/usr/local/glibc/glibc-2.21/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2'
$ cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" -DEXTERNAL_LIBCLANG_PATH=/usr/local/lib/libclang.so . ~/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/third_party/ycmd/cpp
$ make ycm_support_libs
```

```
$ cd
$ .vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/install.sh
```

And finally, YouCompleteMe works again!

Comment: "shared library libtinfo.so.5 still cannot be found" -- it is likely that this is a *system* library installed in `/usr/lib`, or `/lib`, or `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu` or wherever Wheezy installs them. It's also likely that your build of `glibc-2.21` isn't looking there. Try adding system library paths to your `RPATH`, like so: `-Wl,--rpath=/usr/local/glibc/glibc-2.21/lib:/lib:/usr/lib:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu`

Comment: This solved my problem, thanks a lot! `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu` was actually also needed, like this:  `-Wl,--rpath=/usr/local/glibc/glibc-2.21/lib:/lib:/usr/lib:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Then I also tried LD_PRELOAD

As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/851229/50617), in order to use custom glibc, you need to set correct `--dynamic-linker`.

I see that you are using `--dynamic-linker=/usr/local/glibc/glibc-2.21/ld-linux.so.2`, but that doesn't look right: you need `ld-linux-x86-64.so.2`.

> `export LD_PRELOAD='/usr/local/glibc/glibc-2.21/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 ...`

That (preloading of `ld-linux`) can *never* work: it's the `ld-linux` that interprets `LD_PRELOAD` in the first place.

Comment: Please check my edited question for more information.

Comment: @nrz I think I see your problem: you did `-Wl,--dynamic-linker=/usr/local/glibc/glibc-2.21/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2` but you probably want `-Wl,--dynamic-linker=/usr/local/glibc/glibc-2.21/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2` (the latter marches your attempted `LD_PRELOAD`). In any case, make sure the `--dynamic-linker` path actually exists: the "no such file" error you are getting suggests that it doesn't.

Comment: `-Wl,--dynamic-linker=/usr/local/glibc/glibc-2.21/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2` indeed fixed the problem with `llvm-tblgen`, but now shared library `libtinfo.so.5` cannot be found. Please check my recent edit for more info.