# How to tell CMake where to find the directory of a library?

Tags: cmake

I am trying to install [glnemo2](https://projets.lam.fr/projects/glnemo2) on a desktop which I don't have root access. The OS is CentOS. glnemo2 requires CCfits which I installed locally at $HOME/local/CCfits. So, I downloaded and untarred the source file, and following the instruction all I need to do is

```
  cd build
  cmake ..
  make
  make install
```

However, during `make` it complains: `fatal error: CCfits: No such file or directory    #include <CCfits>`.

So, my question is, how to tell cmake where to look for the installed CCfits library?

Comment: `which I installed locally` How did you "install" it to `$HOME`? You want to add include search path to your compiler. Ex. [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25849571/adding-include-directories-to-cmake-when-calling-it-from-the-command-line).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the glnemo2 project:

1. There is no `find_package(CCfits)`
   src: https://gitlab.lam.fr/jclamber/glnemo2/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt
2. They use a `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH`
   https://gitlab.lam.fr/jclamber/glnemo2/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt#L20-21
3. but they do not provide any `FindCCfits.cmake` module
4. They use an ugly (not target_include_directories() + hard coded path):

```
include_directories(/usr/include/CCfits /opt/local/include /opt/local/include/CCfits  /usr/include/cfitsio /usr/local/include/CCfits)
```

src: https://gitlab.lam.fr/jclamber/glnemo2/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt#L156
then an other hackish

```
target_link_libraries (glnemo2 ... CCfits cfitsio ...)
```

src: https://gitlab.lam.fr/jclamber/glnemo2/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt#L230

The quick solution would be to modify these lines,
less hack would be to provide a `findCCfits.cmake` with a let's say target `CCfits::CCfits`.